# org.hibernate.id.IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save():

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I know this question might have been asked before but I am not getting a solution for my problem . I have a primary key column for categoryID of varchar(20) and to which the entity class is mapped by id property. While adding the data its taking an id value entered through the UI, but while editing the other fields and save through the UI its throwing  exception "IdentifierGenerationException: ids for this class must be manually assigned before calling save():"

Please find the code below:

```
          Category.java
          -------------
          package com.niit.cakecuisinebe.model;

          import java.util.UUID;

          import javax.persistence.Column;
          import javax.persistence.Entity;
          import javax.persistence.Id;
          import javax.persistence.PrePersist;
          import javax.persistence.Table;

          import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

        @Entity
        @Table
        @Component
        public class Category {

            @Id
            @Column(name="CATEGORYID")
            private String id;


            public String getId() {
                return id;
            }
            public void setId(String id) {
                this.id = id;
            }
            public String getName() {
                return name;
            }
            public void setName(String name) {
                this.name = name;
            }
            public String getDescription() {
                return description;
            }
            public void setDescription(String description) {
                this.description = description;
            }
            @Column(name="CATEGORYNAME")
            private String name;
            @Column(name="CATEGORYDESCRIPTION")
            private String description;
        }
        CategoryDAOImpl
        ----------------
        package com.niit.cakecuisinebe.dao;

        import java.util.List;


        import javax.transaction.Transactional;

        import org.hibernate.Criteria;
        import org.hibernate.Query;
        import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
        import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
        import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

        import com.niit.cakecuisinebe.model.Category;
        @Repository("categoryDAO")
        public class CategoryDAOImpl implements CategoryDAO{

            @Autowired
            private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

            public CategoryDAOImpl(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
                this.sessionFactory = sessionFactory;
            }

            @Transactional
            public List<Category> list()
            {
                //Logger.debug("calling list");

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                List<Category> listCategory = (List<Category>) 
                          sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                        .createCriteria(Category.class)
                        .setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY).list();
            //  Logger.debug("calling list");
                return listCategory;
            }

            @Transactional
            public Category get(String id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String hql = "from Category where id=" + "'"+ id +"'";
                //  from category where id = '101'
                Query query =  sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);
                List<Category> listCategory = (List<Category>) query.list();

                if (listCategory != null && !listCategory.isEmpty()) {
                    return listCategory.get(0);
                }
                return null;
            }

            @Transactional
            public void saveOrUpdate(Category category) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(category);
            }
            @Transactional
            public void delete(String id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Category category = new Category();
                category.setId(id);
                sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().delete(category);
            }

            @Transactional
            public Category getByName(String name) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String hql = "from Category where name=" + "'"+ name +"'";
                Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery(hql);

                @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                List<Category> listCategory = (List<Category>) query.list();

                if (listCategory != null && !listCategory.isEmpty()) {
                    return listCategory.get(0);
                }

                return null;

            }

        }
        CategoryController
        --------------------
        package com.niit;

        import java.util.List;
        import java.util.Map;

        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
        import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

        import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
        import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
        import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
        import org.springframework.ui.Model;
        import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
        import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

        import com.niit.cakecuisinebe.dao.CategoryDAO;
        import com.niit.cakecuisinebe.model.*;


        @Controller
        public class CategoryController {
            protected static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("CategoryController");
            @Autowired
            private CategoryDAO categoryDao;

            @RequestMapping(value = "/ViewCategory", method = RequestMethod.GET)
            public String getCategory(Model model) {

                logger.info("entering showAllGreetings");
                model.addAttribute("category", new Category());

                List<Category> categories = categoryDao.list();
                if (!categories.isEmpty()) {

                    model.addAttribute("categorylist", categories);
                }

                return "Category";
            }

            @RequestMapping(value = "/addCategory", method = RequestMethod.POST)
            public String addCategory(@ModelAttribute("category") Category category) {
                logger.info("entering showAllGreetings");

                categoryDao.saveOrUpdate(category);

                return "redirect:/ViewCategory";

            }

            @RequestMapping(value = "edit/addCategory", method = RequestMethod.POST)
            public String editCategory(@ModelAttribute("category") Category category) {
                logger.info("entering showAllGreetings");

                String id=category.getId();
                category.setId(id);
                categoryDao.saveOrUpdate(category);

                return "redirect:/ViewCategory";

            }

            @RequestMapping(value = "delete/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
            public String deleteCategory(@PathVariable("id") String id, ModelMap model) {
                logger.info("entering showAllGreetings");

                categoryDao.delete(id);
                model.addAttribute("{msg}", "Successfully Deleted");
                return "redirect:/ViewCategory";
            }

            @RequestMapping(value = "edit/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
            public String showEditCategory(@PathVariable("id") String id, Model model) {
                logger.info("entering showAllGreetings");

                model.addAttribute("category", this.categoryDao.get(id));
                model.addAttribute("categorylist", categoryDao.list());

                return "Category";
            }
        }
        <div  >
        <spring:form method="POST"  action="addCategory" modelAttribute="category" align="center">
        <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" style="height=45px; width=45px; background-color: pink; padding=10px">
            <tr>

                <c:choose>
                 <c:when test="${!empty category.id}">
                  <td><spring:label path="id"><springtags:message text="CategoryID"></springtags:message></spring:label></td>
                  <td><spring:input path="id" disabled="true" readonly="true" /></td>
                 </c:when>
                 <c:otherwise>
                    <td><spring:label path="id"><springtags:message text="CategoryID"></springtags:message></spring:label></td>
                    <td><spring:input path="id" /></td>
                 </c:otherwise>
                </c:choose>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td> Category Name:</td>
                <td><spring:input path="name" /></td>
            </tr>
             <tr>
                <td> Category Description:</td>
                <td><spring:input path="description" /></td>
            </tr>



            <tr>

               <c:if test="${!empty category.id}">
                            <td>    <input type="submit"
                                    value="<springtags:message text="Edit Category"/>" />
                            </c:if> 
                            </td>
                            <td><c:if test="${empty category.id}">
                                <input type="submit" value="<springtags:message text="Add Category"/>" />
                            </c:if>
                            </td>
            </tr>


        </table>
        </spring:form>
            </div>

            <div class="container">
            <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
            <caption><h2>Categories</h2></caption>
            <thead>
              <tr>
              <th>Category ID</th>
               <th>Category Name</th>
               <th>Category Description</th>
               <th>Edit</th>
               <th>Delete</th>
              </tr>
              </thead>
                 <c:if test="${not empty categorylist}" >
                 <tbody>
                    <c:forEach items="${categorylist}" var="category">      
                    <tr>
                    <td>${category.id}</td>
                    <td>${category.name}</td>
                    <td>${category.description} </td>
                    <td><a href="edit/${category.id}">Edit</a> </td>
                    <td><a href="delete/${category.id}">Delete</a> </td>
                    </tr>       
                    </c:forEach>
                </tbody>    
        </c:if>
        <c:if test="${empty categorylist}" >
            There are no category yet. 
        </c:if>
              </tr>


        </table>
        </div>
         <%@ include file="footer.jsp"%>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Please help stuck with this for past 2 days

Comment: `System.out.println(category.getId());` in Controller - What's the output?

Comment: was trying to check if the id is being fetched but it was null I am new to spring and hibernate , I am not able to get it done please help

Comment: which is the controller method that gives the exception? *editCategory?* *addCategory* works fine?

Comment: editCategory @amicoderozer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a big fan of ids in string's type. You should change for a long id. As it, you can delegate the generation of id to the database with some sequencing stuff.

If you want the data in the actual colomn to be unique, just create another field with an unique contraint in it.